# recursively concatenate string in python

Tags: python

I have a recursive function that concatenate a string (and do some logic) and when the logic is done, it finish the function and return the result in the variable.

(my function is quite big so I simplified it.

```
  import random
  def test(str):
      l = len(str)
      if l >= 10:
          return 0
      str += random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
      test(str)

  str = ''
  test(str)
  print str
```

When i "print str" in my function it works, iget:

```
r
rV
rVG
rVGF
rVGFK
rVGFKa
rVGFKat
rVGFKatY
rVGFKatYN
rVGFKatYNY
```

but when I print str (last line of the code) i get an empty string

Comment: First of all, str is a python function, you may want to use a better name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string is not mutable in Python, use for example the return statement or an array of characters if you want the function to actually modify it's input.

This line:

```
str += random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
```

will initialise a new object `str` and assign `str + random.(...)` to it. So the actual object you passed to the function is basically abandoned and later garbage collected.

This is kind of what you're looking for, although it's not the nicest implementation:

```
import random
def test(input_string):
    l = len(input_string)                                                   
    if l >= 10:
        return input_string
    input_string += random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    return test(input_string)                                               

input_string = ''                                                           
input_string = test(input_string)                                           
print(input_string)
```